# What is the difference between these two sentences in Past perfect continuous and past continuous?

Tags: tense

I have learned English tenses but I get confused sometimes when I use them. And now I would like to know the difference between these two sentences.

1. I was playing football when Ali came to join me.

.2 I had been playing football when Ali came to join me.

Answer (score 1):

By itself, 2. means that you had stopped playing football when Ali came to join you (doing something else). But note that the same tense could also make 'I had been been playing football for 10 minutes when Ali came to join me', which means you were still playing football when he joined you.